# Interface inheritance issues in one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, interface, entity-framework-4

I have a domain model specifying the interfaces or my domain and I'm using DI to hook it up to an entity framework 4 repository implementation. In my domain I have the following:

```
public interface IInboundGateway : IGateway
{
    ICollection<IInboundNumber> InboundNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

I then have my entity framework model that has generated the InboundGateway class:

```
public partial class InboundGateway : EntityObject
{
    public EntityCollection<InboundNumber> InboundNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

In order to implement the IInboundGateway inteface I created a partial InboundGateway class.

```
public partial class InboundGateway : IInboundGateway
{
}
```

Eventhough EntityCollection<> implements ICollection<> and InboundNumber implements IInboundNumber I am getting an error reporting that InboundGateway does not implement interface IInboundGateway.InboundNumbers because InboundGateway.InboundNumbers does not have the matching return type `ICollection<IInboundNumber>`

Im pretty certain this is mental as EntityCollection does implement ICollection and InboundNumber does implement IInboundNumber.

Any help would be massively appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware that `EntityCollection<InboundNumber>` is a sub type of `ICollection<InboundNumber>` but is NOT a subtype of `ICollection<IInboundNumber>`. These are 2 different types and are not related. 

so in the entity object class you have:

```
public EntityCollection<InboundNumber> InboundNumbers { get; set; }
```

While the comopiler expects you to have:

```
public ICollection<IInboundNumber> InboundNumbers { get; set; }
```

If you could turn your EntityObjects to POCO, part of the problem would be solved since POCO classes using `ICollection` for their navigation properties by default. Also, you need to change your interface like this:

```
public interface IInboundGateway : IGateway {
    ICollection InboundNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Surely given the fact that InboundNumbers is also partialed inheriting IInboundNumber means that the compiler can see that InboundNumber inherits IInboundNumber? No?

Comment: No, like I said even though InboundNumbers is implementing IInboundNumber but you cannot return ICollection<InboundNumbers> where ICollection<IInboundNumbers> is required. Please note that *Covariance* does NOT work in Generics meaning that List<Apple> is NOT a subtype of List<Fruit>.